# Parse text file into Datatable

Tags: c#, database, parsing

I have a legacy system that can export order information into a text file in the following format, I need to import this data into an MVC web app that has a SQL database back end.

I am using the webclient to obtain the file from a web server but now I need to parse it to import my data.

I need the data inside the double quotes for string fields and the number for numeric.

Here is what the file looks like:

```
SLOCATION   Pub   C  "FTL"  
MQUOTE      Pub   C  " "  
MCPAYDATE   Pub   C  "                    "  
MTAXNO      Pub   C  "                  "  
MCOUNTY     Pub   C  "   "  
MCUSTCAT    Pub   C  "RELIGIOUS ORGANIZATION"  
MRREF       Pub   N           4  (         4.00000000)  
MLREF       Pub   N           7  (         7.00000000)  
MLREC       Pub   N           4  (         4.00000000)  
MSUBTOT     Pub   N          67.4600  (        67.46000000)  
MCALL       Pub   C  " "  
PCATA       Pub   C  "X32-SER   "  
PCATB       Pub   C  "LD        "  
PCATC       Pub   C  "NP        "  
PCATD       Pub   C  "          "  
PCATE       Pub   L  .F.  
PCATF       Pub   L  .F.  
PCATG       Pub   L  .F.  
PCATH       Pub   L  .F.  
PCATI       Pub   L  .F.  
PCATJ       Pub   L  .F.  
PCATK       Pub   L  .F.  
PCATL       Pub   L  .F.  
PCATM       Pub   L  .F.  
PCATN       Pub   L  .F.  
PCATO       Pub   L  .F.  
PQUANA      Pub   N           1.00  (         1.00000000)  
PQUANB      Pub   N           1.00  (         1.00000000)  
PQUANC      Pub   N           1.00  (         1.00000000)  
PQUAND      Pub   N           0.00  (         0.00000000)  
PQUANE      Pub   L  .F.  
PQUANF      Pub   L  .F.  
PQUANG      Pub   L  .F.  
PQUANH      Pub   L  .F.  
PQUANI      Pub   L  .F.  
PQUANJ      Pub   L  .F.  
PQUANK      Pub   L  .F.  
PQUANL      Pub   L  .F.  
PQUANM      Pub   L  .F.  
PQUANN      Pub   L  .F.  
PQUANO      Pub   L  .F.  
PDONEA      Pub   C  "Test Award 6.5 in      
                                 "  
PDONEB      Pub   C  "LAST DONE                             
                                 "  
PDONEC      Pub   C  "John Doe                   
                                 "  
PDONED      Pub   C  "                                      
                                 "  
PDONEE      Pub   L  .F.  
PDONEF      Pub   L  .F.  
PDONEG      Pub   L  .F.  
PDONEH      Pub   L  .F.  
PDONEI      Pub   L  .F.  
PDONEJ      Pub   L  .F.  
PDONEK      Pub   L  .F.  
PDONEL      Pub   L  .F.  
PDONEM      Pub   L  .F.  
PDONEN      Pub   L  .F.  
PDONEO      Pub   L  .F.  
PDTWOA      Pub   C  "                                      
                                 "  
PDTWOB      Pub   C  "654321                                
                                 "  
PDTWOC      Pub   C  "                                      
                                 "  
PDTWOD      Pub   C  "                                      
                                 "  
PDTWOE      Pub   L  .F.  
PDTWOF      Pub   L  .F.  
PDTWOG      Pub   L  .F.  
PDTWOH      Pub   L  .F.  
PDTWOI      Pub   L  .F.  
PDTWOJ      Pub   L  .F.  
PDTWOK      Pub   L  .F.  
PDTWOL      Pub   L  .F.  
PDTWOM      Pub   L  .F.  
PDTWON      Pub   L  .F.  
PDTWOO      Pub   L  .F.  
PUNITA      Pub   N          67.46  (        67.46000000)  
PUNITB      Pub   N           0.00  (         0.00000000)  
PUNITC      Pub   N           0.00  (         0.00000000)  
PUNITD      Pub   N           0  (         0.00000000)  
PUNITE      Pub   N           0  (         0.00000000)  
PUNITF      Pub   N           0  (         0.00000000)  
PUNITG      Pub   N           0  (         0.00000000)  
PUNITH      Pub   N           0  (         0.00000000)  
PUNITI      Pub   N           0  (         0.00000000)  
PUNITJ      Pub   N           0  (         0.00000000)  
PUNITK      Pub   N           0  (         0.00000000)  
PUNITL      Pub   N           0  (         0.00000000)  
PUNITM      Pub   N           0  (         0.00000000)  
PUNITN      Pub   N           0  (         0.00000000)  
PUNITO      Pub   N           0  (         0.00000000)  
PTOTALA     Pub   N          67.4600  (        67.46000000)  
PTOTALB     Pub   N           0.0000  (         0.00000000)  
PTOTALC     Pub   N           0.0000  (         0.00000000)  
PTOTALD     Pub   N           0  (         0.00000000)  
PTOTALE     Pub   N           0  (         0.00000000)  
PTOTALF     Pub   N           0  (         0.00000000)  
PTOTALG     Pub   N           0  (         0.00000000)  
PTOTALH     Pub   N           0  (         0.00000000)  
PTOTALI     Pub   N           0  (         0.00000000)  
PTOTALJ     Pub   N           0  (         0.00000000)  
PTOTALK     Pub   N           0  (         0.00000000)  
PTOTALL     Pub   N           0  (         0.00000000)  
PTOTALM     Pub   N           0  (         0.00000000)  
PTOTALN     Pub   N           0  (         0.00000000)  
PTOTALO     Pub   N           0  (         0.00000000)  
XPTCK       Pub   C  "YES"  
MTUSER      Priv  C  "chris"                                  menumain.prg
SELECTNUM   Priv  N           1.00  (         1.00000000)     menumain.prg
SELECT      Priv  C  "1 "                                     menumain.prg
CONTINUE    Priv  C  "    "                                   newentry.prg
MDATE       Priv  C  "04/16/2018"                             newentry.prg
MPUDATE     Priv  C  "04/23/2018"                             newentry.prg
MPAYDATE    Priv  C  "  /  /    "                             newentry.prg
MGONEDATE   Priv  C  "  /  /    "                             newentry.prg
MSHPNAME    Priv  C  "ATTN: JOHN DOE"                         newentry.prg
MSHPCNME    Priv  C  "TEST COMPANY NAME             "         newentry.prg
MSHPAD1     Priv  C  "ANY STREET                    "         newentry.prg
MSHPAD2     Priv  C  "                              "         newentry.prg
MSHPCITY    Priv  C  "ANY CITY                      "         newentry.prg
MEMAIL      Priv  C  "test@email.com                        
                       "                                      newentry.prg
MPHOTO      Priv  C  "                              "         newentry.prg
MSHPST      Priv  C  "FL"                                     newentry.prg
MSTATE      Priv  C  "FL"                                     newentry.prg
MGONEPER    Priv  C  "  "                                     newentry.prg
MSHPZIP     Priv  C  "33312     "                             newentry.prg
MZIP        Priv  C  "33312     "                             newentry.prg
MSHIPVIA    Priv  C  "UPS GND"                                newentry.prg
MPUTIME     Priv  C  "1300"                                   newentry.prg
MGONETIME   Priv  C  "    "                                   newentry.prg
MCASH       Priv  C  " "                                      newentry.prg
MLETTER     Priv  C  " "                                      newentry.prg
MYTAX       Priv  C  " "                                      newentry.prg
MLABEL      Priv  C  "Y"                                      newentry.prg
MNUMBER     Priv  C  "TEST"                                   newentry.prg
MINVNO      Priv  C  "634835"                                 newentry.prg
MCUSTPO     Priv  C  "3123345             "                   newentry.prg
MSHIPFROM   Priv  C  "ACME Inc       "       newentry.prg
MCONTACT    Priv  C  "JOHN DOE              "                 newentry.prg
MPHONE      Priv  C  "954-111-2211          "                 newentry.prg
MFAX        Priv  C  "954-222-1122          "                 newentry.prg
MCELL       Priv  C  "                      "                 newentry.prg
MCOMMENT    Priv  C  "                                      
                                                    "         newentry.prg
MCOMMENT1   Priv  C  "                                      
                                                    "         newentry.prg
MACCTN      Priv  C  "TEST COMPANY NAME             "         newentry.prg
MSTREET     Priv  C  "ANY STREET                    "         newentry.prg
MCITY       Priv  C  "ANY CITY                      "         newentry.prg
MCHECKNO    Priv  C  "                              "         newentry.prg
MENGRAV     Priv  N           0  (         0.00000000)        newentry.prg
MTAX        Priv  N           4.0500000  (         4.05000000)  newentry.prg
MSHIPPING   Priv  N          15.57  (        15.57000000)     newentry.prg
MTOTAL      Priv  N            87.0800000  (        87.08000000)  newentry.prg
MPAYMENT    Priv  N           0  (         0.00000000)        newentry.prg
MCC         Priv  N           4  (         4.00000000)        newentry.prg
XSALESPER   Priv  C  "CN"                                     newentry.prg
MSNAME      Priv  C  "User  ext 510  "                        newentry.prg
MEVENTDTE   Priv  C  "04/23/2018"                             newentry.prg
MOPENACCT   Priv  C  "Y"                                      newentry.prg
MPAYPERSON  Priv  C  "TEST                          "         newentry.prg
ANS         Priv  C  "Y"                                      newentry.prg
ERASE       Priv  S                                           newentry.prg
MFILENAME   Priv  C  "634835"                                 dailwrte.prg
```

To clarify, here is the model model I would like to build by parsing this data, each file contains data for only one entity:

```
public class Order
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string SLOCATION { get; set; }
        public string MQUOTE { get; set; }
        public string MCPAYDATE { get; set; }
        public string MTAXNO { get; set; }
        public string MCOUNTY { get; set; }
        public string MCUSTCAT { get; set; }
        public int MRREF { get; set; }
        public int MLREF { get; set; }
        public int MLREC { get; set; }
        public decimal MSUBTOT { get; set; }
        public string MCALL { get; set; }
        public string PCATA { get; set; }
        public string PCATB { get; set; }
        public string PCATC { get; set; }
        public string PCATD { get; set; }
        public bool PCATE { get; set; }
        public bool PCATF { get; set; }
        public bool PCATG { get; set; }
        public bool PCATH { get; set; }
        public bool PCATI { get; set; }
        public bool PCATJ { get; set; }
        public bool PCATK { get; set; }
        public bool PCATL { get; set; }
        public bool PCATM { get; set; }
        public bool PCATN { get; set; }
        public bool PCATO { get; set; }
        public int PQUANA { get; set; }
        public int PQUANB { get; set; }
        public int PQUANC { get; set; }
        public int PQUAND { get; set; }
        public bool PQUANE { get; set; }
        public bool PQUANF { get; set; }
        public bool PQUANG { get; set; }
        public bool PQUANH { get; set; }
        public bool PQUANI { get; set; }
        public bool PQUANJ { get; set; }
        public bool PQUANK { get; set; }
        public bool PQUANL { get; set; }
        public bool PQUANM { get; set; }
        public bool PQUANN { get; set; }
        public bool PQUANO { get; set; }
        public string PDONEA { get; set; }
        public string PDONEB { get; set; }
        public string PDONEC { get; set; }
        public string PDONED { get; set; }
        public bool PDONEE { get; set; }
        public bool PDONEF { get; set; }
        public bool PDONEG { get; set; }
        public bool PDONEH { get; set; }
        public bool PDONEI { get; set; }
        public bool PDONEJ { get; set; }
        public bool PDONEK { get; set; }
        public bool PDONEL { get; set; }
        public bool PDONEM { get; set; }
        public bool PDONEN { get; set; }
        public bool PDONEO { get; set; }
        public string PDTWOA { get; set; }
        public string PDTWOB { get; set; }
        public string PDTWOC { get; set; }
        public string PDTWOD { get; set; }
        public bool PDTWOE { get; set; }
        public bool PDTWOF { get; set; }
        public bool PDTWOG { get; set; }
        public bool PDTWOH { get; set; }
        public bool PDTWOI { get; set; }
        public bool PDTWOJ { get; set; }
        public bool PDTWOK { get; set; }
        public bool PDTWOL { get; set; }
        public bool PDTWOM { get; set; }
        public bool PDTWON { get; set; }
        public bool PDTWOO { get; set; }
        public decimal PUNITA { get; set; }
        public int PUNITB { get; set; }
        public int PUNITC { get; set; }
        public int PUNITD { get; set; }
        public int PUNITE { get; set; }
        public int PUNITF { get; set; }
        public int PUNITG { get; set; }
        public int PUNITH { get; set; }
        public int PUNITI { get; set; }
        public int PUNITJ { get; set; }
        public int PUNITK { get; set; }
        public int PUNITL { get; set; }
        public int PUNITM { get; set; }
        public int PUNITN { get; set; }
        public int PUNITO { get; set; }
        public decimal PTOTALA { get; set; }
        public int PTOTALB { get; set; }
        public int PTOTALC { get; set; }
        public int PTOTALD { get; set; }
        public int PTOTALE { get; set; }
        public int PTOTALF { get; set; }
        public int PTOTALG { get; set; }
        public int PTOTALH { get; set; }
        public int PTOTALI { get; set; }
        public int PTOTALJ { get; set; }
        public int PTOTALK { get; set; }
        public int PTOTALL { get; set; }
        public int PTOTALM { get; set; }
        public int PTOTALN { get; set; }
        public int PTOTALO { get; set; }
        public string XPTCK { get; set; }
        public string MTUSER { get; set; }
        public int SELECTNUM { get; set; }
        public string SELECT { get; set; }
        public string CONTINUE { get; set; }
        public string MDATE { get; set; }
        public string MPUDATE { get; set; }
        public string MPAYDATE { get; set; }
        public string MGONEDATE { get; set; }
        public string MSHPNAME { get; set; }
        public string MSHPCNME { get; set; }
        public string MSHPAD1 { get; set; }
        public string MSHPAD2 { get; set; }
        public string MSHPCITY { get; set; }
        public string MEMAIL { get; set; }
        public string MPHOTO { get; set; }
        public string MSHPST { get; set; }
        public string MSTATE { get; set; }
        public string MGONEPER { get; set; }
        public string MSHPZIP { get; set; }
        public string MZIP { get; set; }
        public string MSHIPVIA { get; set; }
        public string MPUTIME { get; set; }
        public string MGONETIME { get; set; }
        public string MCASH { get; set; }
        public string MLETTER { get; set; }
        public string MYTAX { get; set; }
        public string MLABEL { get; set; }
        public string MNUMBER { get; set; }
        public string MINVNO { get; set; }
        public string MCUSTPO { get; set; }
        public string MSHIPFROM { get; set; }
        public string MCONTACT { get; set; }
        public string MPHONE { get; set; }
        public string MFAX { get; set; }
        public string MCELL { get; set; }
        public string MCOMMENT { get; set; }
        public string MCOMMENT1 { get; set; }
        public string MACCTN { get; set; }
        public string MSTREET { get; set; }
        public string MCITY { get; set; }
        public string MCHECKNO { get; set; }
        public int MENGRAV { get; set; }
        public decimal MTAX { get; set; }
        public decimal MSHIPPING { get; set; }
        public decimal MTOTAL { get; set; }
        public decimal MPAYMENT { get; set; }
        public string MCC { get; set; }
        public string XSALESPER { get; set; }
        public string MSNAME { get; set; }
        public string MEVENTDTE { get; set; }
        public string MOPENACCT { get; set; }
        public string MPAYPERSON { get; set; }
        public string ANS { get; set; }
        public string MFILENAME { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC or web  apps. Unless you know what format this is, and there's a library available, you'll have to write your own parser.

Comment: Are there only 4 fields. The last field being text, numeric or .F.? And if so what does the .F. represent? Have you tried writing any code?

Comment: @Kevin: I would assume that the .F. fields are Logic values from the preceding L & they could also be .T.

Comment: This is data out of an old FoxPlus system, It dumps all current memoy varables to standard output that can then be piped to a text file. .F. means false

Comment: You could process the file line by line - using Substring to separate the four fields & a switch statement based on the third to identify Character, Numeric or Logic values in the fourth.

Comment: @PaulF - I would do exactly what PaulF is suggesting if this is a fixed width file (that's what it looks like).

Comment: each line is one field on the database, for the first line the field name is SLOCATION and the Data is FTL, for the sixth line the field is MCUSTCAT and the data is RELIGIOUS ORGANIZATION

Comment: I have given you one suggestion on how you can do this - so why not write some code & try it out. If you have problems then ask another question showing your code & explaining why it is not working as expected.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that, thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try following code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Order(FILENAME);

        }
    }
    public class Order
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string SLOCATION { get; set; }
        public string MQUOTE { get; set; }
        public string MCPAYDATE { get; set; }
        public string MTAXNO { get; set; }
        public string MCOUNTY { get; set; }
        public string MCUSTCAT { get; set; }
        public int MRREF { get; set; }
        public int MLREF { get; set; }
        public int MLREC { get; set; }
        public decimal MSUBTOT { get; set; }
        public string MCALL { get; set; }
        public string PCATA { get; set; }
        public string PCATB { get; set; }
        public string PCATC { get; set; }
        public string PCATD { get; set; }
        public bool PCATE { get; set; }
        public bool PCATF { get; set; }
        public bool PCATG { get; set; }
        public bool PCATH { get; set; }
        public bool PCATI { get; set; }
        public bool PCATJ { get; set; }
        public bool PCATK { get; set; }
        public bool PCATL { get; set; }
        public bool PCATM { get; set; }
        public bool PCATN { get; set; }
        public bool PCATO { get; set; }
        public int PQUANA { get; set; }
        public int PQUANB { get; set; }
        public int PQUANC { get; set; }
        public int PQUAND { get; set; }
        public bool PQUANE { get; set; }
        public bool PQUANF { get; set; }
        public bool PQUANG { get; set; }
        public bool PQUANH { get; set; }
        public bool PQUANI { get; set; }
        public bool PQUANJ { get; set; }
        public bool PQUANK { get; set; }
        public bool PQUANL { get; set; }
        public bool PQUANM { get; set; }
        public bool PQUANN { get; set; }
        public bool PQUANO { get; set; }
        public string PDONEA { get; set; }
        public string PDONEB { get; set; }
        public string PDONEC { get; set; }
        public string PDONED { get; set; }
        public bool PDONEE { get; set; }
        public bool PDONEF { get; set; }
        public bool PDONEG { get; set; }
        public bool PDONEH { get; set; }
        public bool PDONEI { get; set; }
        public bool PDONEJ { get; set; }
        public bool PDONEK { get; set; }
        public bool PDONEL { get; set; }
        public bool PDONEM { get; set; }
        public bool PDONEN { get; set; }
        public bool PDONEO { get; set; }
        public string PDTWOA { get; set; }
        public string PDTWOB { get; set; }
        public string PDTWOC { get; set; }
        public string PDTWOD { get; set; }
        public bool PDTWOE { get; set; }
        public bool PDTWOF { get; set; }
        public bool PDTWOG { get; set; }
        public bool PDTWOH { get; set; }
        public bool PDTWOI { get; set; }
        public bool PDTWOJ { get; set; }
        public bool PDTWOK { get; set; }
        public bool PDTWOL { get; set; }
        public bool PDTWOM { get; set; }
        public bool PDTWON { get; set; }
        public bool PDTWOO { get; set; }
        public decimal PUNITA { get; set; }
        public int PUNITB { get; set; }
        public int PUNITC { get; set; }
        public int PUNITD { get; set; }
        public int PUNITE { get; set; }
        public int PUNITF { get; set; }
        public int PUNITG { get; set; }
        public int PUNITH { get; set; }
        public int PUNITI { get; set; }
        public int PUNITJ { get; set; }
        public int PUNITK { get; set; }
        public int PUNITL { get; set; }
        public int PUNITM { get; set; }
        public int PUNITN { get; set; }
        public int PUNITO { get; set; }
        public decimal PTOTALA { get; set; }
        public int PTOTALB { get; set; }
        public int PTOTALC { get; set; }
        public int PTOTALD { get; set; }
        public int PTOTALE { get; set; }
        public int PTOTALF { get; set; }
        public int PTOTALG { get; set; }
        public int PTOTALH { get; set; }
        public int PTOTALI { get; set; }
        public int PTOTALJ { get; set; }
        public int PTOTALK { get; set; }
        public int PTOTALL { get; set; }
        public int PTOTALM { get; set; }
        public int PTOTALN { get; set; }
        public int PTOTALO { get; set; }
        public string XPTCK { get; set; }
        public string MTUSER { get; set; }
        public int SELECTNUM { get; set; }
        public string SELECT { get; set; }
        public string CONTINUE { get; set; }
        public string MDATE { get; set; }
        public string MPUDATE { get; set; }
        public string MPAYDATE { get; set; }
        public string MGONEDATE { get; set; }
        public string MSHPNAME { get; set; }
        public string MSHPCNME { get; set; }
        public string MSHPAD1 { get; set; }
        public string MSHPAD2 { get; set; }
        public string MSHPCITY { get; set; }
        public string MEMAIL { get; set; }
        public string MPHOTO { get; set; }
        public string MSHPST { get; set; }
        public string MSTATE { get; set; }
        public string MGONEPER { get; set; }
        public string MSHPZIP { get; set; }
        public string MZIP { get; set; }
        public string MSHIPVIA { get; set; }
        public string MPUTIME { get; set; }
        public string MGONETIME { get; set; }
        public string MCASH { get; set; }
        public string MLETTER { get; set; }
        public string MYTAX { get; set; }
        public string MLABEL { get; set; }
        public string MNUMBER { get; set; }
        public string MINVNO { get; set; }
        public string MCUSTPO { get; set; }
        public string MSHIPFROM { get; set; }
        public string MCONTACT { get; set; }
        public string MPHONE { get; set; }
        public string MFAX { get; set; }
        public string MCELL { get; set; }
        public string MCOMMENT { get; set; }
        public string MCOMMENT1 { get; set; }
        public string MACCTN { get; set; }
        public string MSTREET { get; set; }
        public string MCITY { get; set; }
        public string MCHECKNO { get; set; }
        public int MENGRAV { get; set; }
        public decimal MTAX { get; set; }
        public decimal MSHIPPING { get; set; }
        public decimal MTOTAL { get; set; }
        public decimal MPAYMENT { get; set; }
        public string MCC { get; set; }
        public string XSALESPER { get; set; }
        public string MSNAME { get; set; }
        public string MEVENTDTE { get; set; }
        public string MOPENACCT { get; set; }
        public string MPAYPERSON { get; set; }
        public string ANS { get; set; }
        public string MFILENAME { get; set; }

        public Order() { }
        public Order(string filename)
        {

            string patternNumber = @"\d+(.\d+)?";

            //use string read instead of StreamReader if data is going from a web response
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
            string inputLine = "";
            string type = "";

            while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                inputLine = inputLine.Trim();
                if (inputLine.Length > 0)
                {
                    if(!inputLine.StartsWith("\""))
                    {
                        string name = inputLine.Substring(0, 12).Trim();
                        type = inputLine.Substring(12, 9).Trim();
                        string value = inputLine.Substring(21).Trim();


                        switch (type)
                        {
                            case "Pub   C" :
                                Write(name, value.Replace("\"", "").Trim());
                                break;
                            case "Pub   N":
                                string strNumber = Regex.Match(value, patternNumber).Value;
                                object num = strNumber.Contains(".") ? decimal.Parse(strNumber) : int.Parse(strNumber);
                                Write(name, num);
                                break;
                            case "Pub   L":
                                bool true_false = value == ".F." ? false : true;
                                Write(name, true_false);
                                break;
                        }

                    }


                }
            }
        }
        public void Write(string name, object value)
        {
            switch(name)
            {
                case "Id" :
                    Id = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "SLOCATION" :
                    SLOCATION = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MQUOTE":
                    MQUOTE = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MCPAYDATE":
                    MCPAYDATE = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MTAXNO":
                    MTAXNO = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MCOUNTY":
                    MCOUNTY = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MCUSTCAT":
                    MCUSTCAT = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MRREF":
                    MRREF = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "MLREF":
                    MLREF = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "MLREC":
                    MLREC = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "MSUBTOT":
                    MSUBTOT = (decimal)value;
                    break;

                case "MCALL":
                    MCALL = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "PCATA":
                    PCATA = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "PCATB":
                    PCATB = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "PCATC":
                    PCATC = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "PCATD":
                    PCATD = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "PCATE":
                    PCATE = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PCATF":
                    PCATF = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PCATG":
                    PCATG = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PCATH":
                    PCATH = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PCATI":
                    PCATI = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PCATJ":
                    PCATJ = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PCATK":
                    PCATK = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PCATL":
                    PCATL = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PCATM":
                    PCATM = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PCATN":
                    PCATN = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PCATO":
                    PCATO = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PQUANA":
                    PQUANA = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "PQUANB":
                    PQUANB = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "PQUANC":
                    PQUANC = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "PQUAND":
                    PQUAND = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "PQUANE":
                    PQUANE = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PQUANF":
                    PQUANF = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PQUANG":
                    PQUANG = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PQUANH":
                    PQUANH = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PQUANI":
                    PQUANI = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PQUANJ":
                    PQUANJ = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PQUANK":
                    PQUANK = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PQUANL":
                    PQUANL = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PQUANM":
                    PQUANM = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PQUANN":
                    PQUANN = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PQUANO":
                    PQUANO = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PDONEA":
                    PDONEA = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "PDONEB":
                    PDONEB = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "PDONEC":
                    PDONEC = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "PDONED":
                    PDONED = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "PDONEE":
                    PDONEE = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PDONEF":
                    PDONEF = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PDONEG":
                    PDONEG = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PDONEH":
                    PDONEH = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PDONEI":
                    PDONEI = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PDONEJ":
                    PDONEJ = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PDONEK":
                    PDONEK = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PDONEL":
                    PDONEL = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PDONEM":
                    PDONEM = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PDONEN":
                    PDONEN = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PDONEO":
                    PDONEO = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PDTWOA":
                    PDTWOA = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "PDTWOB":
                    PDTWOB = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "PDTWOC":
                    PDTWOC = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "PDTWOD":
                    PDTWOD = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "PDTWOE":
                    PDTWOE = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PDTWOF":
                    PDTWOF = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PDTWOG":
                    PDTWOG = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PDTWOH":
                    PDTWOH = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PDTWOI":
                    PDTWOI = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PDTWOJ":
                    PDTWOJ = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PDTWOK":
                    PDTWOK = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PDTWOL":
                    PDTWOL = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PDTWOM":
                    PDTWOM = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PDTWON":
                    PDTWON = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PDTWOO":
                    PDTWOO = (bool)value;
                    break;

                case "PUNITA":
                    PUNITA = (decimal)value;
                    break;

                case "PUNITB":
                    PUNITB = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "PUNITC":
                    PUNITC = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "PUNITD":
                    PUNITD = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "PUNITE":
                    PUNITE = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "PUNITF":
                    PUNITF = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "PUNITG":
                    PUNITG = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "PUNITH":
                    PUNITH = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "PUNITI":
                    PUNITI = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "PUNITJ":
                    PUNITJ = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "PUNITK":
                    PUNITK  = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "PUNITL":
                    PUNITL = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "PUNITM":
                    PUNITM = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "PUNITN":
                    PUNITN = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "PUNITO":
                    PUNITO = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "PTOTALA":
                    PTOTALA = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "PTOTALB":
                    PTOTALB = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "PTOTALC":
                    PTOTALC = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "PTOTALD":
                    PTOTALD = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "PTOTALE":
                    PTOTALE = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "PTOTALF":
                    PTOTALF = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "PTOTALG":
                    PTOTALG = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "PTOTALH":
                    PTOTALH = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "PTOTALI":
                    PTOTALI = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "PTOTALJ":
                    PTOTALJ = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "PTOTALK":
                    PTOTALK = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "PTOTALL":
                    PTOTALL = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "PTOTALM":
                    PTOTALM = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "PTOTALN":
                    PTOTALN = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "PTOTALO":
                    PTOTALO = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "XPTCK":
                    XPTCK = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MTUSER":
                    MTUSER = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "SELECTNUM":
                    SELECTNUM = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "SELECT":
                    SELECT = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "CONTINUE":
                    CONTINUE = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MDATE":
                    MDATE = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MPUDATE":
                    MPUDATE = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MPAYDATE":
                    MPAYDATE = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MGONEDATE":
                    MGONEDATE = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MSHPNAME":
                    MSHPNAME = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MSHPCNME":
                    MSHPCNME = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MSHPAD1":
                    MSHPAD1 = (string)value;
                    break;


                case "MSHPAD2":
                    MSHPAD2 = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MSHPCITY":
                    MSHPCITY = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MEMAIL":
                    MEMAIL = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MPHOTO":
                    MPHOTO = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MSHPST":
                    MSHPST = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MSTATE":
                    MSTATE = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MGONEPER":
                    MGONEPER = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MSHPZIP":
                    MSHPZIP = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MZIP":
                    MZIP = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MSHIPVIA":
                    MSHIPVIA = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MPUTIME":
                    MPUTIME = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MGONETIME":
                    MGONETIME = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MCASH":
                    MCASH = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MLETTER":
                    MLETTER = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MYTAX":
                    MYTAX = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MLABEL":
                    MLABEL = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MNUMBER":
                    MNUMBER = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MINVNO":
                    MINVNO = (string)value;
                    break;


                case "MCUSTPO":
                    MCUSTPO = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MSHIPFROM":
                    MSHIPFROM = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MCONTACT":
                    MCONTACT = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MPHONE":
                    MPHONE = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MFAX":
                    MFAX = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MCELL":
                    MCELL = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MCOMMENT":
                    MCOMMENT = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MCOMMENT1":
                    MCOMMENT1 = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MACCTN":
                    MACCTN = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MSTREET":
                    MSTREET = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MCITY":
                    MCITY = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MCHECKNO":
                    MCHECKNO = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MENGRAV":
                    MENGRAV = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "MTAX":
                    MTAX = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "MSHIPPING":
                    MSHIPPING = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "MTOTAL":
                    MTOTAL = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                    break;

                case "MPAYMENT":
                    break;

                case "MCC":
                    MCC = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "XSALESPER":
                    XSALESPER = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MSNAME":
                    MSNAME = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MEVENTDTE":
                    MEVENTDTE = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MOPENACCT":
                    MOPENACCT = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MPAYPERSON":
                    MPAYPERSON = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "ANS":
                    ANS = (string)value;
                    break;

                case "MFILENAME":
                    MFILENAME = (string)value;
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will give me a datatable with the same format as the text file but the text file contains data for a single entity, each field downwards on the left column is a property of the entity and the "L_Value" field is the data for that property.  Can you change your code to build a model instead?

Comment: I just edited the question to offer clarification.  I need to build a model like the one above with this data.

Comment: Just make sure I didn't make any dumb typos.